# Writing a simple regex class only gives empty results

Tags: java, class

I'm fairly new to classes in java so I just thought I'd have a go at writing a simple regex class. And I failed.

Here is the class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class HRM_SwallowTableExtractor {
    String x;
    String pattern;
    ArrayList<String> myArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    public HRM_SwallowTableExtractor(String x,String pattern) {
        x=this.x;
        pattern=this.pattern;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> SwallwTabExtract(String x,String pattern) {
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher matcher_pattern = pat.matcher(x);

        while (matcher_pattern.find()) {
            String p=matcher_pattern.group(1).trim();
            String [] arr=p.split("\\s");
            for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                myArray.add(arr[i]);
            }
        }
        return myArray;
    }
}
```

and here in the main class:

```
String UESRecovTime_pattern="(UES_recovery_time_\\(msec\\).*)";
HRM_SwallowTableExtractor swallTabExtract=new HRM_SwallowTableExtractor(stuff,UESRecovTime_pattern);
```

However when I run this I only get an empty array returned. I think the problem is that the pattern is not being found (yes it is in the text body). In turn I think this has something to do with how the main text is being brought into the instantiated class (as String x) or with how the Pattern is instantiated. I don't know how to figure this one out. I haven't put the text up that I am using but happy to if its needed.

Answer (score 2):

You get an empty array because maybe you have misunderstood the local variables and *instance* variables, or you have just made an inversion mistake;

```
 public HRM_SwallowTableExtractor(String x,String pattern) {
    //x=this.x; //this should be invert 
    this.x = x; //you should try this
    pattern=this.pattern;
}
```